# Java. Создание пустого .txt на рабочем столе - ошибка компиляции

Tags: java, компиляция

Изучаю Java с нуля, есть вопрос.

Почему этот код, который должен создать пустой текстовый документ на рабочем столе, при попытке скомпилировать выдает ошибку?

```
package filecreator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName = "My File.txt";
        String filePath = "/Users/Donrumata/Desktop/";

        File myFile = new File(filePath + "/" + fileName);

        try {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Если отформатировать код, сразу становится видно, что не хватает фигурной скобки. Форматируйте код!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы привели весь код в классе, то в конце не хватает точки с запятой и закрывающей фигурной скобки после нее.

---

Пока писал ответ, увидел ответ про лишний слэш. Опытным путем выяснил, что их количество в пути не играет роли. Следующий код создаст файл в той же дирректории, что и код из вопроса:

```
String fileName = "My File.txt";
String filePath = "/Users/Documents/Desktop/";
File myFile = new File(filePath + "//////" + fileName);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Действительно, не хватало фигурной скобки (а где именно не хватает точки с запятой? После добавления фигурной скобки все скомпилировалось.)

Comment: @MaximVelichkin с точкой запятой я погорячился. Поставил её после метода, но она там не нужна. Рад был помочь!

Comment: П.с правильнее использовать не /. А File.separator(там еще String версия есть), почему, думаю узнаете.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров не сразу вспомнил об этом. Спасибо, что напомнили о способе) На сколько я понимаю для того чтобы разделитель не зависел от платформы Windows/Linux

Comment: Да, + не надо думать об экранизации /, от этого читабельность и да Windows/Linux